# How to rename a duplicate column inside the nested JSON using spark scala dynamically

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a `nested JSON dataset` that is flattened using `Spark` scala. Further, when I am trying to flatten it, it is not flattened due to `duplicate` columns. So, I have to rename it first and then flatten it but, I am unable to do so. Below is my code to flatten the dataset:

```
def flattenDataframe(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    //getting all the fields from schema
    val fields = df.schema.fields
    val fieldNames = fields.map(x => x.name)
    //length shows the number of fields inside dataframe
    val length = fields.length
    for (i <- 0 to fields.length - 1) {
      val field = fields(i)
      val fieldtype = field.dataType
      val fieldName = field.name
      fieldtype match {
        case arrayType: ArrayType =>
          val fieldName1 = fieldName
          val fieldNamesExcludingArray = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName1)
          val fieldNamesAndExplode = fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array(s"explode_outer($fieldName1) as $fieldName1")
          //val fieldNamesToSelect = (fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array(s"$fieldName1.*"))
          val explodedDf = df.selectExpr(fieldNamesAndExplode: _*)
          return flattenDataframe(explodedDf)

        case structType: StructType =>
          val childFieldnames = structType.fieldNames.map(childname => fieldName + "." + childname)
          val newfieldNames = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName) ++ childFieldnames
          val renamedcols = newfieldNames.map(x => (col(x.toString()).as(x.toString().replace(".", "_").replace("$", "_").replace("__", "_").replace(" ", "").replace("-", ""))))
          val explodedf = df.select(renamedcols: _*)
          return flattenDataframe(explodedf)
        case _ =>
      }
    }
    df
  }
```

After flattening the dataset it looks like below:

[image]

I have used the below loop for renaming duplicate columns but it is working fine for the JSON elements which are on the `same level`:

```
val orgList = df.columns.toList // take the original list
 val dupsList = orgList.map(.toLowerCase()).diff(orgList.map(.toLowerCase()).distinct).distinct //take the duplicate columns list in lower case
var i = 1
    var newDf: DataFrame = df
    for (dups <- dupsList) {
      i=1
      for (key <- orgList) {
        if (key.toLowerCase() == dups) {
          newDf = newDf.withColumnRenamed(key, key + "_" + i)
          i += 1
          //println(i)
        }
      }
    }
```

How do I rename it before flattening it?